# Color in counties on a map

Tags: r, ggmap

I have a list of counties that I would like to color in on a map, but the only way I've found to do it is with lat/long.  This is not as accurate as I want to make sure all the counties are represented and not just a dot.

Is it possible to color in the county borders?

### Example:

dput:

```
    db_loc <- structure(list(X = 1:10, fips = c(5001L, 5001L, 5001L, 5001L, 
5001L, 5001L, 5001L, 5001L, 5001L, 5001L), zip = c(72003L, 72026L, 
72038L, 72042L, 72048L, 72055L, 72073L, 72140L, 72160L, 72166L
), city = c("Almyra", "Casscoe", "Crocketts Bluff", "De Witt", 
"Ethel", "Gillett", "Humphrey", "Saint Charles", "Stuttgart", 
"Tichnor"), latitude = c(34.403216, 34.505369, 34.438327, 34.283347, 
34.28965, 34.109348, 34.396301, 34.383661, 34.479852, 34.061917
), longitude = c(-91.40953, -91.30213, -91.26907, -91.32515, 
-91.13632, -91.36875, -91.66201, -91.15428, -91.53854, -91.24828
)), .Names = c("X", "fips", "zip", "city", "latitude", "longitude"
), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

### Map Data:

```
library(ggmap)

map <- get_map(location='arkansas', zoom=8, maptype = "terrain",
             source='google',color='color')

ggmap(map) + geom_point(
                aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, show_guide = TRUE), 
                data=db_loc, alpha=.8, na.rm = T)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: you'll need polygons for the counties.

Comment: You say `counties` in your question, but your data seems to differentiate at the zip level...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are packages in R that can help you use these out of the box. There are ample instructions and examples here:
https://github.com/arilamstein/choroplethr

You should be able to install chroplether via standard install, i think:
`install.packages("choroplethr")`

[image: county maps in color]

If you prefer, you could go get your own map from the US census bureau website here:

As of 10/09/2015, this link was valid:
https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_counties.html

Get the shapefiles or the kml files. If you don't know what those are, just google it. `rgdal` package should read that.  Again, read the manuals. That will give you a structure with the outlines of all counties.

---

Most counties have a [FIPS code](https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/codes/cou.html), you must key your data on either the FIPS code or on the geoIDs from the rgdal file. Choroplethr should automate this to some degree. Just follow [their examples here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/choroplethr/vignettes/c-county-choropleth.html).

---

If that's still too hard, here's a fully worked out example. I haven't used your data, since it contains only one county (FIPS 05001, Arkansas County).

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)    # for reproducible example
map.county <- map_data('county')
counties   <- unique(map.county[,5:6])
akcounties <- counties[counties$region=="arkansas",]
akcounties

#This is where you'd select whatever you want to plot
# `Obesity` is the first thing to come to mind
# no offense meant to the people of the great state of Arkansas :)
# it's defined as a random uniform draw between 0-100 in the 3rd line below:
obesity_map <- data.frame(state_names=akcounties$region, 
                          county_names=akcounties$subregion, 
                          obesity= runif(nrow(akcounties), min=0, max=100))
```

# replace the value above with whatever variable you want to plot, 
   # and a subset of the counties you actually care about

```
library(data.table)   # use data table merge - it's *much* faster
map.county <- data.table(map.county[map.county$region=="arkansas",])
setkey(map.county,region,subregion)
obesity_map <- data.table(obesity_map)
setkey(obesity_map,state_names,county_names)
map.df      <- map.county[obesity_map]

ggplot(map.df, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=obesity)) + 
geom_polygon()+coord_map()
```

[image: pic arkansas]

Comment: Thanks for the links.  I've looked at the `choroplethr` package before, but the data must be in county and value columns to plot correctly.

Comment: haha, so put it in county and value columns. You'll need to give R some values to color by, or specify the color by hand.

Comment: Thanks for the updated example.  I guess my point was that I don't have values as I just want to show the represented counties.  I guess the shading helps identify the individual counties, so maybe I'll work off of that.

Comment: @Amstell, pro tip: specifiy `fill='black'` (or whatever color) and `alpha=0.3` to get a nice transparent shading on your map. you may want to combine the above with a google map background, too.

Comment: FYI, the latest verison of choroplethr (v3.3.0) allows you to combine a choropleth map with a reference map, which it appears the OP wants to do: http://www.arilamstein.com/blog/2015/09/30/combining-choropleth-maps-and-reference-maps-in-r/.

Comment: @Ari, thank you for the work you put into the package, Ari! I use it all the time!